# Is it possible to use aws sdk for upload data to s3 from file path

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, react-native

I am using aws sdk to upload file to s3 like:

```
let params = {
   Body: fileInBase64Format...
};

s3.upload(params);
```

What I am trying to do is to avoid loading file in memory like this but I want to make it like this:

```
let params = {
   Body: 'file:///...path-to-file.mov'
};
s3.upload(params);
```

I am using react native v0.44
Is it possible to upload file like this but avoid base64?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add your file path to a filestream and then just run *S3.putObject* method to upload it to s3.

```
var fStream = fs.createReadStream("file:///...path-to-file.mov");
var Parameters = {
    Bucket: s3bucket,
    Key: newkey,
    Body: fStream 
};
s3.putObject(Parameters, function(Error, Data){
    if(Error){
        console.error(Error);
    } else {
        console.log(Data);
    }
});
```

Hope It will help!

Comment: What is 'fs'? Does react native has this?

Comment: Ohh I totally didn't missed React native part,its a Node.js inbuilt function. I am not sure its alternative in react.